# Unexpected behaviour for to_date() with week number and week day

Tags: postgresql, date-format

I tried to convert a date string (year, week, day of week = `'YYYY-WW-D'`) into a date using the `to_date()` function.

I got these results ([demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=05123b6c3129cd872cd144e55bd60867)):

```
date string |  to_date()
-------------------------
'2019-1-1'  |  2019-01-01
'2019-1-2'  |  2019-01-01
'2019-1-3'  |  2019-01-01
'2019-1-4'  |  2019-01-01
'2019-1-5'  |  2019-01-01
'2019-1-6'  |  2019-01-01
'2019-1-7'  |  2019-01-01

'2019-2-1'  |  2019-01-08
'2019-2-2'  |  2019-01-08
```

It is not clear to me, why this results in the same date for every day of a week.

If I take the ISO format instead (`'IYYY-IW-ID'`) this works as expected ([demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=5c490cdb825e4bf986acb452a7848969)):

```
date string |  to_date()
-------------------------
'2019-1-1'  |  2018-12-31
'2019-1-2'  |  2019-01-01
'2019-1-3'  |  2019-01-02
'2019-1-4'  |  2019-01-03
'2019-1-5'  |  2019-01-04
'2019-1-6'  |  2019-01-05
'2019-1-7'  |  2019-01-06

'2019-2-1'  |  2019-01-07
'2019-2-2'  |  2019-01-08
```

Why does it work for the ISO pattern, not for the standard pattern? What am I missing here?

Comment: What's more, `SELECT to_date(('2019-1-8'), 'IYYY-IW-ID')` should not result in `'2019-01-06'` but in an exception. This formatting code is hugely complex and there are still corner case errors. Looks like you found one. Consider a [bug report](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/bug-reporting.html), maybe after presenting your case in [pgsql-general](https://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-general/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior [is documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html):

> In `to_timestamp` and `to_date`, weekday names or numbers (`DAY`, `D`, and related field types) are accepted but are ignored for purposes of computing the result. The same is true for quarter (`Q`) fields.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But nevertheless it feels like a bug. An documented one, but a bug. Or is there any known reason for that? Do you know any?

Comment: Probably nobody thought this was a sufficiently interesting thing to spend development effort on. I don't think that there is a deep reason. If you feel motivated, have a go!

Comment: I tried :) https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/c2a5dc4bd855db7b58303031e46c5b9e%40four-two.de